# How to list all active sessions in Gnome shell

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell, wayland

(System: Ubuntu 17.04 x64, official Gnome flavor, GNOME Shell 3.24.2 Wayland)

I have been experimenting with [Gnome Shell extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org) and some of them cause the session to crash. 
I have noticed that sometimes just a new session is generated as processes from the previous session are still active (using `ps`).

Question: What is the command to view all Gnome sessions?

(Follow up question) Is there a way to dump the current session and 'join' another active session?

Comment: Do you see a `gnome-session` process?

Comment: yes, I tried poking around the documentation for `gnome-session` but no luck.

Comment: I actually found `loginctl list-sessions` is what I was after. There is also `loginctl activate [ID]` that has yet to work seamlessly, but I will keep tinkering with and STW for the correct process.

Comment: Perhaps you can post `loginctl list-sessions` as an answer, so the question is marked answered? :)

Answer (score 4):

Gnome has a tool to manage concurrent sessions:

```
loginctl
```

This tool list sessions:

```
SESSION  UID USER  SEAT  TTY 
    173 1000 jehon seat0 tty2

1 sessions listed.
```

The tool also have a "kill session" utility:

```
loginctl terminate-session 173
```

Comment: Thanks to @erixun and on suggestion of Lucas Werkmeister